# Using support library in Android Java

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I want to set up Toolbar but when I import support libary, I have a problem:

```
"Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:32.0.0"
```

[image: Code Snapshot]

Comment: Please dont post screen shots. Your gradle config is pure text. Your error messages are pure text. Take the time to learn how to use the markdown language to nicely format/indent TEXT, and then replace that screen shot with TEXT (and please see [mcve], too).

Comment: Yes latest version of support libraries are 28.+

Comment: use com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"

Comment: @Sumit what about comiplesdk and targetsdk. I should set 28